# how to speedup amazon EMR bootstrap?

Tags: amazon-emr

I'm using amazon EMR for some intensive computation, but, it takes around 7 min to start computing, is there some clever way to have my computation starting immediately ? The computation is a python stream started from a user-faced website, so I can't really afford a long startup.

I might have simply missed an option in the ocean that is amazon AWS. I just want simplicity to launch jobs (that's what I used EMR), scalability, and pay only for what I use (and startup time is not useful).

Comment: just adding another datapoint...I have a 5 c4.large OnDemand node cluster that's been bootstrapping for 45min.  And another, similar cluster bootstrapping for 15min.  Grr...

Comment: bootstrapping for 90min...time to terminate!

Comment: this morning a similar cluster (to my prev comment) took 15min.  then another cluster is taking 45min and counting...

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but had some insights I would add to the next searcher who finds this thread in hope of speeding up bootstrap times on Amazon EMR.

For a while I have wondered why my clusters took so long to start, usually about 15 minutes.  This takes a pretty big chunk of time for a job that usually completes in under 1 hour.  Sometimes it pushes the job past 1 hour, but I think thankfully AWS does not charge for the full boot strap time.

The last couple days I noticed my startup times were improved.  You see the spot market became very volatile during April and the first week of May.  Normally, I start my cluster entirely of spot instances, as failure is an option, and the cost savings justifies the technique in my case.  However, after waiting 14 hours for clusters to start, I had to switch to OnDemand, I only have so much patience, over night usually exceeds it.  The OnDemand clusters start in about 5 minutes.  Now having switched back to spot as the madness seems to have abated, I am back to 15 minutes for a cluster.

So if you are using Spot instances on your Core or Master nodes, expect a longer startup time.  I will be experimenting with using a small set of OnDemand in the core and augmenting with a large number of spot instances to see if it helps startup and deals better with Spot Market volatility.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using all spot instances, and some times start fairly quickly (<10min anyway), and sometimes longer (15 and counting for my current cluster). I wouldn't think that spot vs OnDemand would effect startup time, but what do I know?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that as well, sometimes it is pretty quick but often not.  I basically assume 7 min for spot instance negotiation and 7 min for bootstrap now.

Comment: Why would spot instances take longer to start? It appears that way (anecdotally), but if your bid exceeds the spot there shouldn't be any additional delay—notwithstanding the small chance that your purchase pushes the price up before all the nodes can be allocated.

Comment: I agree, but it seems it takes them several minutes to process the bid.  At least that is my take based on as you say anecdotal experience.

Comment: The best possible thing would be to use a pre-baked AMI, then needed thing would be the shef-puppet tie-up.  But then you will have to move away from Amazons process of provisioning of EMR. so 15 mins explanation given by @AaronM is the tradeoff to the complexity you can avoid

Comment: The bidding time seems to also be dependent on the amount of your bid. When you bid slightly higher than the minimum spot price, it will setup faster.

Comment: Actually, AWS does charge you on warm-up times... "You are charged per-second from the time your cluster starts until it is terminated, with a one-minute minimum." https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty normal and there is little you can do about it. I'm starting 100+ node clusters and I've seen them take 15+ minutes before they start processing. Given the amount of work thats going on in the background I'm pretty happy to allow them the 15 minutes or so to get the cluster configured and read in whatever data maybe required. Nature of the beast I'm afraid.

Comment: Just for the record: GCP's analogue Dataproc was able to bootstrap cluster ~3 years ago just in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your data source hosted?

If on S3 (probably), if you have many tiny files, it's the latency of each connection (per file) that is taking the time.

If that's the only reason then, your 7 mins of start-up time will translate to ~5 mins of reading from S3 time => ~1GB input files on S3

Comment: the source is a main 30Mo file plus 5-6 other config files on on the side, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: What kind of instances do you use? anything less than mediums for core nodes will yield bad performance.

Comment: Having data on S3 doesn't matter for bootstrap time.

Comment: This answer is very much irrelevant to the question asked. data in s3 has nothing to do with the cluster launch time.